# disable button in fragment from main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 buttons in a fragment and I want to disable them from the main activity. I have tried to use the bundle option before replace() newfragment but it created other issues. Can a button in a fragment be casted to a main activity ?  Something like this. I get the error cannot cast but my entries are incorrect.

```
            RedUp = (ButtonControls) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.btnRedUP);
```

Here is my main.xml this holds the fragment called rgb_controls

```
        <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/rgb_controls"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="550dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is the button in the fragment xml called button_controls.xml

```
        <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnRedUP"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:text="UP"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Here is the fragment actiivty

```
    public class ButtonControls extends Fragment {

public Button RedUp, RedDn, GreenUp, GreenDn, BlueUp, BlueDn;

View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_controls, container, false);

    RedUp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnRedUP);
    return view;

       }

           }
```

Fragment is added using the replace()

```
                Fragment ButtonFragment = new ButtonControls();
        ButtonFragment.setArguments(bundle);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.rgb_controls, ButtonFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the thing:

```
ButtonControls fragment = (ButtonControls)
    getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rgb_controls);
fragment.setButtonsGone();
```

You have to actually implement this `setButtonsGone` method in `ButtonControls`. Something as:

```
public void setButtonsGone() {
    RedUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RedDn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    GreenUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    GreenDn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    BlueUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    BlueDn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: I get error cannot cast   ButtonControls fragment = (ButtonControls)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rgb_controls);
   fragment.setButtonsGone();

Comment: How are you adding the fragment?

Comment: I already made the change to target the rgb_controls. See my answer above.

Comment: I made a change from getfragmentManager to the following and it builds fine but crashes.   ButtonControls fragment = (ButtonControls)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rgb_controls);
   fragment.setButtonsGone();